# How to train SVM in matlab / python for MultiLabel data?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I am training a problem such that my output (y) could be more than one class. For example, the SVM could say, this input vector is class 1, but it could also say, this input vector is classes 1 AND 5. This is not the same as a multiclass SVM problem, where the output could be ONE of multiple classes. My output could be ONE or SEVERAL of multiple classes.

Example: My training data looks like (for each training vector X)

```
X_1   [1 0 0 0]
X_2   [0 1 1 0]
X_3   [0 0 0 1]
X_4   [1 1 0 1]
```

Where the right side is the Y to be predicted (here I am showing an example with 4 classes, where a 1 indicates class membership).

I understand that I need to probably use a structural SVM such as discussed here: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vedaldi/svmstruct.html

However, this is all very confusing to me.

I do NOT want to simply do one-vs-all classifiers for each of the possible output classes, however. I need to somehow take into account class relationships, so I guess what I need is a structural SVM. My training data will have some instances tagged with single classes and other instances tagged with multiple classes.

I guess I'm asking how to tackle this problem and if you know any packages to do so in MATLAB or python.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the scikit-learn [multiclass and multilabel algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) or the [MEKA](http://meka.sourceforge.net/) tool and the scikit-multilearn that can interface to MEKA in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of scikit-multilearn I can recommend using it from the python perspective, as it is by far the largest multi-label classification library in python and is very convienient to use with scikit. You should probably use the master version from github instead of the release 0.0.1 from 2 years ago. We are planning a release next week, which is a very large updated, with new classifiers and many others. It also lets you interface with meka.

In your case, with 4 labels, you can get good results with one of the basic problem transformation methods - label powerset or classifier chains, located in skmultilearn.problem_transform.lp and skmultilearn.problem_transform.cc - more complicated methods are useful mostly in cases of large label imbalance which does not often happen with 4 labels.

You can get the library at https://github.com/scikit-multilearn/scikit-multilearn and install it in pip from git via:

`pip install git+https://git@github.com:scikit-multilearn/scikit-multilearn.git`